# Build a particular cloud contract using gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm building a gradle project to execute all spring cloud contracts by using the following command

```
./gradlew clean build
```

This is taking a lot of time to build. If I want to build a particular contract, I'm not able to find any command.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it. You can file a feature request of you're interested in adding this functionality